# How to get all values from a JSON object for a highscore system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been looking around trying to find a half decent way of getting this done.
Essentially I have a JSON object called `BeginnerNicknameScores`. It contains string keys of `nickname` and the associated values `score`.

I am using the `SimpleJSON` namespace, because it was used in a tutorial but I can of course change the namespace and adjust my code according.

Essentially my goal here is to get all the `score` values from the JSON object, sort into the top 5 scores and display them as text.

```
public void DisplayBeginnerHighscores()
    {
        //declare top 5 interger variables
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        int five = 0;

        //BeginnerNicknameScores is the JSON Object
        //BeginnerNicknameScores.Values is an emerator contraining all the [scores] value
        //Thus I use MoveNext() to check all the values, then sort them into top five using the if statements
        while (Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.MoveNext())
        {
            if(Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current > one)
            {
                one = Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current;
                BegNum1.text = one.ToString();
            }
            else if(Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current > two)
            {
                two = Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current;
                BegNum2.text = two.ToString();
            }
            else if (Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current > three)
            {
                three = Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current;
                BegNum3.text = three.ToString();
            }
            else if (Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current > four)
            {
                four = Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current;
                BegNum4.text = four.ToString();
            }
            else if (Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current > five)
            {
                five = Highscore.BeginnerNicknameScores.Values.Current;
                BegNum5.text = five.ToString();
            }
        }      
    }
```

Thing is, I must be doing something wrong because whenever I load the object containing this script, and thus calling this function, my Unity Engine crashes.

If anyone has any suggestions as to another way to go about this problem I would definitely appreciate it. It might be worth noting that one the scores are separated into top five, I will also need to display the associate nicknames of each score, in my Highscore menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        var scores = new List<Score>
        {
            new Score("Bart", 100),
            new Score("Maggie", 75),
            new Score("Lisa", 50),
            new Score("Marge", 25),
            new Score("Homer", 0)
        };

        var table = new ScoreTable(scores);

        // save to JSON
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(table, true);

        // load from JSON
        var fromJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<ScoreTable>(json);

        // print the top 3 players

        var take = fromJson.Scores.OrderByDescending(s => s.Points).Take(3);

        foreach (var score in take)
            Debug.Log($"{score.Name}: {score.Points}");
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ScoreTable
{
    public List<Score> Scores = new List<Score>();

    public ScoreTable()
    {
        // for serializer
    }

    public ScoreTable([NotNull] List<Score> scores)
    {
        if (scores == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scores));

        Scores = scores;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Score
{
    public string Name;
    public int Points;

    public Score()
    {
        // for serializer
    }

    public Score(string name, int points)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = points;
    }
}
```

Generated JSON:

```
{
    "Scores": [
        {
            "Name": "Bart",
            "Points": 100
        },
        {
            "Name": "Maggie",
            "Points": 75
        },
        {
            "Name": "Lisa",
            "Points": 50
        },
        {
            "Name": "Marge",
            "Points": 25
        },
        {
            "Name": "Homer",
            "Points": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The top 3 players:

[image]

No need for fancy external library, just Unity's one :)

Comment: [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) is actually not a "fancy external library" but was the way to go before `JsonUtility` written by the community ^^ In some cases when you only want one single field from a huge JSON it is better to use that one instead of `JsonUtility` since than you don't have to implement a whole class for representing the intire JSON structure though you only want to use one or more little parts of it ;) In this case you are right and I would also prefere `JsonUtility` since OP already states that he wants to `get all values`

Comment: This is great, but how do I go about saving and loading this to and from persistent storage?

Comment: You can use `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText` to store the JSON, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2 in conjunction with `Application.dataPath` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html to write to an authorized location (unsure about Android though, you'll need to investigate)